# Quitting Ruby Ri

Tags: ruby

When you run the Ruby ri command from an OS X term window to look at documentation for a particular command, how do you "quit" the documentation?  At the end of the document, an (END) is displayed but I don't see how to quit this.  I've tried CTRL-C, CTRL-D, Esc, etc. and I can't find the right key combination.  I've searched online and apparently this is so obvious that no one's bothered to document.

Answer (score 6):

This is [less](http://www.gnu.org/software/less/), unless you changed the value of the environment variable PAGER. Type 'q' or 'ZZ'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'q'?